# Eclipse project "save as"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm quite new to android programming and I was wondering if there is a `Save As` button in Eclipse for the entire project instead of saving only 1 XML or Java at a time.

For example, when I work on Excel, sometimes I like to save different versions of Excel workbooks so that I can roll back if there is a problem. I want to do the same thing for Eclipse project files like `Listv1`, `List v2`, `Listv3` etc.

I know you can use [local history](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-LocalHistory.htm), but that is more for different versions of the XML and Java files. 
I want to save different versions of project files onto my hard drive so that I can compare two different versions of my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on your open project in either the Project Explorer or Package Explorer windows. Then File/Copy (or Ctrl-C), then immediately File/Paste (or Ctrl-V). Your'll get a wizard to save the project under a new name.

Comment: oh my word. That was so simple! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks a lot Scott!

Comment: While that will work, I don't think it's the cleanest approach. In particular, Eclipse knows how to deal with different version control systems, can make context-sensitive diffs etc. Having lots of different copies on the file-system is a crude facsimile of a version control system - why not use the real thing?

Comment: I agree that using a version control system is an important part of a proper software development process. But cloning a project is also a useful tool. It can be useful when one wants to experiment with an existing project, but not worry about breaking (or probably even saving) it. Another common reason for using Save-as is when one wants to start a new project that's substantially similar to an existing project.

Comment: @scottt but 'cloning a project for experiment' scenario is covered in most of the VCS, you can create branches of your project very quickly and in this way you can keep control of what you modify in each one

Comment: Yes, most (all?) modern VCSs have that capability and I currently use it frequently in SVN and Git. In a past life, I've been the guy who enforced use of the various process tools, so you're preaching to the choir. But I also frequently do quick clones that live for a very short time before being deleted. For those, I personally find the sans-VCS approach the best tool for the job, but YMMV. The OP will indeed be well-served to learn and use the proper tools, but in the meantime he can use this low-tech method.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, when I work on excel, sometimes I like to save different versions of excel workbooks so that I can roll back if there is a problem.

Learn to use a good source control (version control) system. That's a *much* cleaner solution than just keeping lots of different copies around. You should still be able to compare different versions easily - and you can experiment on different branches, etc. It'll also make it much easier to share your code with others, should you wish to.

Additionally, it's not clear whether you're currently just a hobbyist or not, but if you're intending to code professionally you'll *definitely* need to get used to source control systems. (Every software company worth their salt uses source control.)

You might want to look at:

- Git (you might want to start at [GitHub](https://github.com/))
- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)
- [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)

(All of these are free, and have Eclipse plug-ins available.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm a hobbyist and definitely not a professional programmer. I will have a look at the links, I'm looking for something that's easy to start with.

Comment: @Simon: Even for a hobbyist I still think a version control system is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need a lot more than manual saves: Any software project of any significant size should be using a *version-control system*. The one that's become the main standard these days is [git](http://git-scm.com).

Providing this sort of multiple versioning is the baseline that a VCS does, and most also handle situations like branching, where you can be working on the new version of your program but still go back and fix a bug in the old one, then push out a fix to the existing users while you keep working on the new version.

Eclipse has very good integration via the [eGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit) plugin, and you might also be interested in the [git-flow branching system](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that eclipse has that feature, why not having a a version control system to track your changes? like Git or Svn, they are free and very powerful